# Removing and adding values in Array or ArrayList (efficiently) - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, ischecked

I'm a bit stuck with an exercise I'm making. 
I basically have 4 buttons and have to hide one if a checkbox is checked. 
I don't know why but I just can't figure out how to do this, should I make an arrayList instead of an array and remove/add the value constantly or is there another way to 'hide' or not use a value?

Hope my explanation is a bit clear, thanks in advance! :)

Here's the code MainActivity.java code (not including imports):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String globalColor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setColor();
    }

    private int randomColor(int length){
        return (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
    }

    private void setColor(){
        String [] colors = {"Green", "Blue", "Red", "Magenta"};

        //ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();

        int rndColor = randomColor(colors.length); //color name for text
        int rndColor2 = randomColor(colors.length); //color for text color

        if(rndColor2 == rndColor){
            rndColor2 = randomColor(colors.length);
        }

        globalColor = colors[rndColor];

        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color);
        v.setText(colors[rndColor]);
        v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colors[rndColor2]));
    }

    public void checkColor(View v){
        Button b = (Button)v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

        TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        if(buttonText.equals(globalColor)){
            txtview.setText("Yaay");

            setColor();
        } else {
            txtview.setText("Booo");

            setColor();
        }
    }

    private void hideMagenta(){
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    //this is where my problem is; I want to remove magenta as an option
                    //is it better to do this with an arraylist and to remove and add magenta to the arraylist
                    //or is there a different, more efficient way
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a list, don't use an array list, use a LinkedList.  Reason-  ArrayList internally still uses an array.  Removing something from the middle is inefficient.  A LinkedList uses a structure of pointers-  its just as face to iterate through, and far easier to remove stuff from.  Its negative is that random access is slower.

Comment: @GabeSechan oh ok! I'd never heard of it, I'll definitely check it out then, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tons of options. You can use an ArrayList like you suggested, you can pass the list of available colors to the `setColor` method. Maybe you can pass the color you don't want to use and then when randoming do `if(randomedColor == colorYouDontWant) then random again`. You can even use `Map<String, Color>` and put all the colors in there and then just delete them from this map, randoming would be quite weird tho. Or `Map<String, Boolean>` where key would be color and value would be if color is available or not (true if available, false otherwise). I suggest using ArrayList.

btw. this fragment:

```java
if(rndColor2 == rndColor){
  rndColor2 = randomColor(colors.length);
}
```

I understand that you don't want colors to be the same, but what if randoming again is gonna give the same result? You should do:

`while(rndColor2 == rndColor)`

Comment: Wow thank you so much, those are all great suggestions! 
I think I'll start with the ArrayList or setColor parameter solution, I was just scared the ArrayList one would be a bit redundant to add and remove. 
I'll also incorporate the while loop, you're totally right. thank you :)